# Spring - Is it more optimal to use Interface-based projections than Class-based Projections (DTOs)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

So I stumbled upon two choices for projections, interface vs classes.

My question is, is it really better to choose class-based projections (use of DTO) than an interface? Isn't the concept of a DTO about retrieving only information rather than the entity itself? If yes, then isn't the interface projection more suited for that as it is only an interface? I'm speaking of course if it's better for performance or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> retrieving only information rather than the entity itself?

If you need the only partial content of the entity or complex data from several tables you should use DTO/projection.

> isn't the interface projection more suited for that as it is only an interface?

I prefer to use [interface-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) because they have some advantages over class-based ones:

1) they are easier to implement (it's just an interface)

2) they can be [open](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open) - so we can extend their functionality

3) we must use a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) of class-based projection in your custom query, unlike the interface-based, compare:

```
Query("select m.name as name from Model m") 
List<ModelProjection> getModelList();

Query("select new com.example.ModelDto(m.name) from Model m") 
List<ModelDto> getModelList();
```